# Method for Calculating Higher Moments

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

During my studies I've come across this "shortcut" for calculating higher moments. How is this method (of calculating moments by summation of a combination of lower moments) called, and how does it work in general?

In particular, I've seen it used for Poisson and Binomial distribution.

> Example: E[X³] = E[X(X-1)(X-2)] + 3E[X(X-1)] + E[X]

While generally x(x-1)(x-2) + 3x(x-1) + x = x³, I believe (X-1) above refers to a previous realization of the random variable X. (?)

[Example for E[X^3] and E[X^4]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKRww.jpg)

Comment: Expectation is a linear operator, so to some extent the identities you ask about might just be implications of that fact.  On the other hand,some relationships could depend on the probability distribution of the random variable(s).

Comment: Everything you want to know about these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_moment

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, the term "Factorial Moment" is a sufficient first pointer. The corresponding Wikipedia article is quite short, but was helpful in combination with this thread:

[Calculating factorial moment for distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465006/calculating-factorial-moment-for-distributions)