# Expected value simplification

Tags: probability

If I'm asked to find, for a random variable $X$, $E[(x-1)^2]$ given a value for $E[x]$ and a moment generating function for the variable, can I just simplify it to 
$E[x^2 - 2x + 1] = E[x^2]+4E[x]$?

Comment: I think just take the expected value as E(x^2)-2E(x) not +4E(X)

Comment: But there is a special property that says for E(ax + b)=a^2E(x)

Comment: To me, $E[x]$ has no sense. And $$E[(X-1)^2]=E[X^2-2X+1]=E[X^2]-2E[X].$$ Do you confuse with the variance ? Since $Var(aX)=a^2Var(X)$.

Comment: Related: [Method for calculating higher moments](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506477/method-for-calculating-higher-moments)

Answer (score 1):

The expectation $ \text{E} [X] $ is a linear operator. Then, writing the expectation either a continuous random variable $ X $ distributed as $ f_{x}(x) $

$$ \text{E} [X] = \int x \, f_{x}(x) dx $$

or a discrete random variable $ X $ with events $ x $ belonging to a finite alphabet of events $ \mathcal{X} = \left\lbrace x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{n} \right\rbrace $ with probabilities $ \text{Pr} (x_{i}) $

$$ \text{E} [X] = \sum_{i} x_{i} \text{Pr} (x_{i}) $$

and subtituting $ x $ by $ (x - 1)^2 $ we obtain

$$ \text{E} [(X -1)^2] = \text{E}[X^2] - 2\text{E}[X] + 1 $$

Comment: It's good to point out the linearity of the expectation operator as a common property of the discrete and continuous versions.